# Regex multiline mode not working as expected for optional group

Tags: php, regex, phpunit, preg-match-all, pcre

I have a next text source:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....................E.....R.................................   61 / 1485 (  1%)
.....................                                         1485 / 1485 (100%)

Time: 1.51 minutes, Memory: 102.00MB

---error details skipped---

ERRORS!
Tests: 1485, Assertions: 14821, Errors: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I need to parse in real time (streamed output to stdout) next symbols: `EFWIRS.` (error, failure, warning, etc) and if available statistics line (numbers and percent in EOL). So, in results I except something like that:

```
.......
```

or

```
.....................E.....R.................................
```

or

```
.....................E.....R.................................   61 / 1485 (  1%)
```

or

```
.....................                                         1485 / 1485 (100%)
```

but not

```
.....................E.....R.................................   61 / 1485 (
```

or

```
.....................E.....R.................................   61 / 1485 (  1
```

or

```
.....................E.....R.................................   61 /
```

My regex is `/^[EFWIRS.]+\s*(?:\d+\s\/\s\d+\s\(\s*\d+%\)\n)?/m` but it also match extra `ERR` string in case if tests failed (look at output example). I try `/^[EFWIRS.]+\s*(?:\d+\s\/\s\d+\s\(\s*\d+%\))?$/m`, but this regex is skip lines with incompleted statistics block completely and match only whole string despite the optional group `(...)?`, that works in first regex as expected.

P.S. I know about custom printers for PHPUnit, but in my case they are not suitable and I need to parse common output.

Comment: Does adding a dot pattern at the start help? [`^\.+[EFWIRS.]+\s*(?:\d+\s\/\s\d+\s\(\s*\d+%\)\n)?`](https://regex101.com/r/r6e5a9/1)?

Comment: Nope, because string can start not only from dot: E, F, W, I, R, S chars is also possible.

Comment: So how can you differentiate between a good and a bad pattern? No `ERR` at the start? [`^(?!ERR)[EFWIRS.]+\s*(?:\d+\s\/\s\d+\s\(\s*\d+%\)\n)?`](https://regex101.com/r/r6e5a9/2)?

Comment: The strings that should be matched is placed between two empty lines: first one is after "PHPUnit 5.7...." and second is before "Time...". Also, second empty line is not always exists (as I say before - this is streamed output)

Comment: @Alex You can also parse the report file. Just saying.

Comment: Nope, I cant, because report file is generated after all tests are executed, but in my case real time output processing is required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use lookahead to ensure both correct characters to match and correct consequence of them in a line.

I've made an example for you [here](https://regex101.com/r/mzhycm/2). The pattern itself is `^([EFWIRS.](?=[EFWIRS.\s]))+\s+(\d+\s*\/\s*\d+\s*\(\s*\d+%\s*\))?$` I am not sure about your mechanism of output capturing so can't advise on modifiers and which PHP regex functions to use. Example down by the link assumes full multiline text so it uses global and multiline modifiers (meaning `preg_match_all` and `#pattern#m` would be used in php code).

Comment: No luck. As I say before, regex should match also "incomplete" strings, like ```................E...........F................................   61 / 1485 (  4%``` (no extra parenthesis at the EOL) or ```................E...........F................................   6```. Both incomplete strings should be matched as ```................E...........F................................``` if block at the EOL ```61 / 1485 (  4%``` is incomplete. Not working example: https://regex101.com/r/mzhycm/3

Answer (score 0):

### This simple regex works in all provided examples if you don't need the statistics part.

`[.EFWIRS]+(?=\s+\d)`.

[Link to the regex](https://regex101.com/r/R3MRyz/1)

Negative lookahead suites better in this case than non-capturing group.

Comment: But statistics part should be also captured, look at original post right after "So, in results I except something like that".