# Regex multiline mode with optional group skip valid data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre, multiline

Consider next example:

```
$payload = '
ababaaabbb =%=
ababaaabbb =%=
ababaa     =%=
';

$pattern = '/^[ab]+\s*(?:=%=)?$/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $payload, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Expected and actual result of match is:

```
"ababaaabbb =%="
"ababaaabbb =%="
"ababaa     =%="
```

But if `$payload` changed to

```
$payload = '
ababaaabbb =%=
ababaaabbb =%=
ababaa     =%'; // "=" sign removed at EOL
```

actual result is

```
"ababaaabbb =%="
"ababaaabbb =%="
```

but expected is

```
"ababaaabbb =%="
"ababaaabbb =%="
"ababaa     "
```

Why this happen? Group `(?:=%=)?` is optional due to `?` and last string in payload should be also present in match results.

Comment: put the end of line anchor inside the optional group: `(?:=%=$)?`

Comment: Oh, it works! But, how? ```$``` in multiline mode stands for "before \n or EOL", so, it should work in case with string "ababaa     =%", because optional part with "=%=" is not valid, but EOL can be reached with ```$```, or i can put "\n" in the end.

Comment: When the optional group fails (with my suggested change), the pattern doesn't need to reach the end of the line to succeed, the match stops at the last space or at the last a or b if there are no spaces.

Comment: Very strage for me: i supposed that if optional (sic!) group match is failed, the match is proceed, but not stop on this first fail.

Comment: Oh, i cant mark your comment as correct answer due to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question Maybe, you move it to separate post here, that I mark as solution?

Comment: Won't `^([ab]+\s*)(?:=%=$)?` also match `ab` in a line that has `abcd`?

Comment: Yep, it will match ```abcd```, but this is ok for this example: actual problem is optional group and the EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your current regex graph:

[image]

The `=%=` *is* optional (see how the branch between `white space` and `End of line` forks), but the EOL *is required*. That means **after one or more `a` or `b` symbols, and zero or more whitespaces, EOL must occur**. However, you have `=%` on your 3rd line => NO MATCH.

Now, when you move the `$` anchor into the optional group:

[image]

The end of line is now *optional*, too, and the match will be returned after matching 1+ `a` or `b` chars and optional whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation!

Comment: :) "Seeing is believing."

Answer (score 0):

Since last line is ending with `=%`, you should make last `=` optional as well and use a capturing group for your expected data:

```
/^([ab]+\s*)(?:=%=?)?$/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/10)

**PS:** Your expected result is available in captured group #1

Comment: Look at the last line of the expected result.

Comment: Nope, because only ```=%=``` or nothing should be matched.

Comment: Your last line ends with `=%` only so why is that line included in expected result?

Comment: The real world question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808736/regex-multiline-mode-not-working-as-expected-for-optional-group There you can see for what i need last line in this case.

Comment: ok sure I will address that question separately. If you think this question is duplicate then feel free to delete it.

Comment: Maybe there is some misunderstanding :) Your question is not duplicate anything, I just show you real-world example for what the last line should be also captured. Question i refer is also asked by me.

Comment: ok then please clarify for which inputs this regex doesn't work?

Comment: Its not working for input like ```ababaa     =``` or ```ababaa     ```. The expected result in both cases is "ababaa     " (without \n at the and). And, to be clear, "=%=" part can be a more complex, as described in question about phpunit, but simplified here for more clear example.

Comment: Question is not making any sense now. If only `=%=` or `=%` is allowed after `[ab]+` then why is `abcd` a valid input?

Answer (score 0):

The group `(?:=%=)?` is optional in your regular expression. That *does not* mean each part of that group is also optional.

Your regex works only if it sees a string of `a`s and `b`s, optional whitespace, then either (1) `=%=` and the end of the line or (2) just the end of the line. It will not work if it sees a string of `a`s and `b`s, whitespace, then anything other than exactly `=%=` or the end of the line. So, `=%` won't work.

To accomplish what you apparently want to do, you need to make the second `=` optional, like so:

```
$pattern = '/^[ab]+\s*(?:=%=?)?$/m';
// see the additional ? here^
```

But it seems like you don't want the `=%` *at all* in this scenario, which means you need to get more creative still:

```
$pattern = '/^[ab]+\s*(?:(?:=%=)?$|(?==%$))/m';
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X78qXB/1).

Comment: In my case, optional part is ```=%=```, ```=%```, ```=``` and nothing. I am surprised with your "It will not work if it sees a string of ```a```s and ```b```s, whitespace, then anything other than exactly =%= or the end of the line.". I thought, that optional group - if it not matched - just "skipped" at EOL is matched by ```$```, that leads to all strings like "aabb =%" is matched.

Comment: Well, if you also want to allow just `=` at the end of the line, change my second example to `$pattern = '/^[ab]+\s*(?:(?:=%=)?$|(?==%?$))/m';` (notice the `?` after the `%`). Optional groups *are* skipped if they don't match, but the whole pattern still has to match. Imagine if you remove the optional group from your regex, leaving `/^[ab]+\s*$/m`. That doesn't match `ababaa     =%` because there's something (`=%`) between the whitespace and the end of the line.